# what is the purpose of adding generic while fetching data using API in angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am testing an angular app, I am not clear with api fetching data. I see generic (Device []) and this generic is a class with properties that is different from properties fetched by the api.  Please look at the code snippet below, I don't understand if this really affects the api fetching data.

```
Device.ts
export class Device {
    DeviceId: string;
    type: String;
    idtype: String;
}

Actual compoenent.ts
getData(){
  this.http.post<Device[]>('/api/getEntitlements', this.filter)
   subscribe(res => {......})
}

Data fetched by API are

End Customer|Account: "jdfdbdfbh"
End Customer|AccountName: "gefege"
End Customer|UserEmail: "something@djdj.com"
End Customer|UserFirstName: "",
DeviceId:"fjhjd"
```

I see there are some additional properties that doesn't exist Device.ts and also some of the properties in Device.ts are not fetched at all. Then what is the purpose of adding Device[] while fetching data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a type in Typescript doesn't do anything with the actual data. For example in your case:

```
this.http.post<Device[]>('/api/getEntitlements', this.filter)
```

When you give a type `Device[]` to the post method you say that the returned data will be of type `Device[]`, a post will return an Observable so it will be an Observable of type `Device[]`.

Giving a type is useful for writing code, editor intellisence and helpful in debugging.

For example when you say that the returned data from API will be of type `Device[]` and if under your subscription you do something like: `res.data`, an intelligent editor will show an error coz an array has no prop `data` in it.

If the returned data and the type you have given for `post` differ then you should give an appropriate type which suites all the properties of the returned data.

Comment: @karansys If you think that the added answer solved your problem, you can also accept answers. See this link here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work